# LabView XY Graph with large number of traces, matching legend and plot data?

Tags: user-interface, graph, labview

I have an XY graph with a large number of traces.  Is there a way to have the user easily determine which legend trace belongs with the plot trace? For example, perhaps they could click on the plot's trace and see the legend text?  See the [attached image for an example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGz7A.png)[image].  As you can see from the attached image, the automatic coloring scheme quickly cycles through all the easily discernible options, making matching the legend and plot data difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The graph should have a method which returns the nearest plot to a given point. You can use either the Mouse Move or the Mouse Down events for the graph to get these coords and wire them into the method. You can then use the ActivePlot property to select that plot and then use the plot properties to get the info you want and present it using indicators. I would also consider using this to make all the plots except the one you're looking the same color. For that, you will need to cycle through all of them using the ActivePlot property.